# finding isolated rings in postgis

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, pgrouting, osm2pgsql

I want to find the isolated rings in an OSM dump loaded into PostGIS, using pgRouting. I need to do this in order to delete the isolated rings of the network. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this before with a graph generated by osm2po. I used a brute force approach : walking the entire graph starting from a known node.

Assuming your pgrouting table is called osmpgr with a source_node_id and target_node_id column and no reverse cost (i.e. if two nodes are connected in both ways, you have to lines with source id and target id switched) :

1. Create a temporary table (tmptable) to hold node ids that are in the main network, and their "completed" status (i.e. a completed node is a node for which all connected nodes have been checked)
2. Insert in this table the node id of a node known to be connected to the main network
3. Loop

   1. Insert all nodes connected to the nodes present in the temporary table, something like : 
      `INSERT INTO tmptable (node_id) 
      SELECT target_node_id 
      FROM osmpgr 
      WHERE source_node_id IN (SELECT node_id FROM tmptable WHERE NOT completed);`
   2. Update the temporary table to set the 'completed' status of all nodes for which there all the connected nodes are already in the table, something like : 
      `UPDATE tmptable 
      SET completed = true
      WHERE NOT completed
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM osmpgr WHERE source_node_id = tmptable.node_id);`
   3. Repeat until 0 row is inserted in step 1.
4. The temporary table will hold all the node_ids that constitute the main network. All node ids that are in osmpgr and not in this table can be considered as isolated networks.

I had to do this on the European OSM extract, and it ran in a reasonnable amount of time (1 to 2 hours if I remember correctly).

I'd probably have to adapt this to your own data structure, depending on whether you have reverse costs or not for instance.

I could have shared my own script but at the time it was written in VBS, which would probably not be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks!. When you say "Insert in this table the node id of a node known to be connected to the main network", you mean that I've to check the connection of that node using pgRouting's routing algorithms?

Comment: When I had to do this I picked a node manually. I just selected a node close to the edge of the network (i.e. in Portugal for instance) on a primary street. This way I was sure that it was part of the "main" network (All primary roads lead to Rome ;)). There are actually not many isolated networks, most of them are poorly designed parking alleys or service roads that should be connected. Or sometimes real islands, if you don't import ferries into your pgrouting graph.